# Optimal Configuration for Disgusing Identity of Scraping

Tags: hosting, screen-scraping, ip-address, domain-name

I'm running a bunch of scripts that are scraping data from a website.  For reasons I won't bore you with, I can't run them all off the same host--instead I need to set up six different hosts.  I want to configure my hosting setup to disguise the fact that all six hosts have the same owner.

I have gotten six different shared hosting accounts that are located in different geographical locations.  Is there anything else I need to do?  Should a buy a different domain name for each host?  If not, what domain should I give to each host?

Comment: I have a feeling those reasons would not bore me in the least.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might get more responses if you could provide an ethical justification for why you are doing this.

Comment: Have you checked whether the Website owner has a public API you can use instead?

Comment: Yeah, they don't have an API unfortunately, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up multiple instances of [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/), configure each with a seperate control port, and run your scrapes on one computer, each using a separate TOR.  This will make each HTTP request jump through separate chains of proxies, and therefore when they get to the desired site, they will be coming from a unique IP.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I'll check out TOR.  Just to confirm--the domain name is irrelevant here, right?  IP address is all that matters for detection purposes?